# Resource Exhausted when training a neural network - keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I have a dataset of 65668 files.

I am using Keras for a CNN, and these are my layers:

```python
embedding_layer = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
                        EMBEDDING_DIM,
                        weights=[embedding_matrix],
                        input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                        trainable=True)
sequence_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)
x = Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu')(embedded_sequences)
x = MaxPooling1D(5)(x)
x = Conv1D(256, 5, activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(5)(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
preds = Dense(len(labels_index), activation='softmax')(x)
```

First embedding layer is trained on GloVE.6B.100d.
Fitting the data:

```python
# fitting the data
model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
      epochs=20, batch_size=128)
```

The `MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH` is 500.
I am training on the GPU, Nvidia GeForce 940MX,
and I get the following error as part of the stack :

> Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[15318793,100] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc

I tried reducing batch size to 16, even 8 and I still get the same error.
What can the issue be?

Comment: OOM := Out of Memory.  Reduce your batch size.

Comment: I did reduce it down to 8, and I still got that.
How much smaller does it need to be?

Comment: `tensor with shape[15318793,100]` looks pretty big, is it from `embedding_layer`?

Comment: Yes.
When I had trainable='false' for that layer, I didn't get the error when reducing the size.
But I need it to be trainable.

Comment: Have you trained this embedding on your own?

Comment: I use GloVe, which is trained on Wikipedia.
I reduced it to using the 50d instead of 100d, but I still get the same :|

Answer (score 8):

The problem lies in your `Embedding`. It needs to allocate a matrix of size `15318793 * 100 * 4 bytes = 5.7 GB` which is definitely greater than `GeForce 940 MX` memory. There are few ways on how you could overcome this issue:

1. **Decrease the vocabulary/corpus size**: Try to take e.g. 1M most frequent words instead of full words set. This will drastically decrease the embedding matrix size.
2. **Use generators instead of `Embedding`**: Instead of using `Embedding` you could use a generator to transform your sequences into word vectors sequences.
3. **Use linear transformation of `Embedding` instead of retraining your embedding** - as you mentioned that with flag `trainable=False` made your algorithm working you can set it to `False` and add:

   ```
   Dense(new_embedding_size, activation='linear')(embedding)
   ```

   to train a new embedding based on existing one.
4. **Change device** - if you have huge `RAM` memory you can try the following strategy:

   ```
   with tf.device('/cpu:0'):    
       embedding_layer = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
           EMBEDDING_DIM,
           weights=[embedding_matrix],
           input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
           trainable=True)
       sequence_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
       embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)
   ```

   In this design computations of `Embedding` layer would be made using `CPU` and `RAM`. The downside is the fact that transfer between `RAM` and `GPU` might be really slow.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikely that you have a dataset large enough to cover all the words in the GloVE embeddings, so setting the embedding to be trainable might cover only some percent of the embedding, so when you train it, those embeddings will move to a slightly different space, but the untouched ones will remain in the original GloVE space. Try setting trainable=False and fix the problem by performing a linear transformation such as:

```
sequence_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)
x = TimeDistributed(Dense(EMBEDDING_DIM))(embedded_sequences)
x = Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu')(x)
```

as another commenter said.
This is important because if you use this for inference in production, one of the untouched embeddings might make the model go quite nuts.
The linear transformation moves the embedding space around and this will work in such a way that it ideally should perform acceptably to unseen data.