# Keras Tensorflow Graph Split between GPU and CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, word-embedding

I was curious about how Keras deals with CPU and GPU allocation under the hood. Unfortunately, the documentation on the Keras site is pretty limited in this regard.

I was having trouble with my `Embedding` layer fitting in memory so I followed the instructions in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48797513/2471385) and forced only my `Embedding` layer to be on the CPU, with the rest (Dense layer, etc.) on the GPU. I don't have any issues now, but was curious how this works.

Is there a version of the graph on both the CPU and GPU? Or is data passed to the rest of the graph on the GPU after embedding is done? If so, how are weights trained?